# Hyperledger fabric chaincode instantiation fail

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, instantiation, chaincode

Chaincode instantiation fails with the following error: `Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg chaincode registration failed: container exited with 0`

Edit: To provide more clarity I include entire log: The log shows three different errors but I am not sure whether they are directly connected to each other.

```
# peer error

 2020-01-10 12:54:21.891 UTC [endorser] ProcessProposal -> DEBU 38963 Entering: request from 172.28.0.6:43260
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.891 UTC [protoutils] ValidateProposalMessage -> DEBU 38964 ValidateProposalMessage starts for signed proposal 0xc0035c1a40
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.891 UTC [protoutils] validateChannelHeader -> DEBU 38965 validateChannelHeader info: header type 3
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.891 UTC [protoutils] checkSignatureFromCreator -> DEBU 38966 begin
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.891 UTC [msp] GetManagerForChain -> DEBU 38967 Returning existing manager for channel 'twoorgschannel'
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.891 UTC [protoutils] checkSignatureFromCreator -> DEBU 38968 creator is &{org1MSP fabd4d26bfe7d6cb51fdcd055a36213137ee0d94b2d9349857e76685ab7d3394}
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.891 UTC [protoutils] checkSignatureFromCreator -> DEBU 38969 creator is valid
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.891 UTC [msp.identity] Verify -> DEBU 3896a Verify: digest = 00000000  b9 8f 40 de 04 73 0f 9d  d5 60 cf 2a d6 4f 41 46  |..@..s...`.*.OAF|
 00000010  16 a4 86 8a 3e f2 0c fe  76 a4 84 44 0f 27 e6 19  |....>...v..D.'..|
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.891 UTC [msp.identity] Verify -> DEBU 3896b Verify: sig = 00000000  30 45 02 21 00 ce 9b 3c  8a 45 99 12 15 55 45 a1  |0E.!...<.E...UE.|
 00000010  06 11 93 a3 9e 1a 5c 32  a6 14 71 1d 1e d1 1f b7  |......\2..q.....|
 00000020  fe 26 8f 35 05 02 20 29  a1 78 44 02 79 ee 7c 25  |.&.5.. ).xD.y.|%|
 00000030  01 c3 ba 23 88 8a fc 83  d1 03 57 14 02 5b 25 a5  |...#......W..[%.|
 00000040  2e bd 4b cb 72 a9 b8                              |..K.r..|
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.891 UTC [protoutils] checkSignatureFromCreator -> DEBU 3896c exits successfully
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.891 UTC [protoutils] validateChaincodeProposalMessage -> DEBU 3896d validateChaincodeProposalMessage starts for proposal 0xc00302d420, header 0xc0035c1f90
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.891 UTC [protoutils] validateChaincodeProposalMessage -> DEBU 3896e validateChaincodeProposalMessage info: header extension references chaincode name:"lscc"
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.891 UTC [endorser] preProcess -> DEBU 3896f [twoorgschannel][344eacf7] processing txid: 344eacf74fbcddd9c9e3c70dbabbe4088c96dd52f98ce2245d1a62ce1e1bbec6
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.891 UTC [fsblkstorage] retrieveTransactionByID -> DEBU 38970 retrieveTransactionByID() - txId = [344eacf74fbcddd9c9e3c70dbabbe4088c96dd52f98ce2245d1a62ce1e1bbec6]
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.891 UTC [lockbasedtxmgr] NewTxSimulator -> DEBU 38971 constructing new tx simulator
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.891 UTC [lockbasedtxmgr] newLockBasedTxSimulator -> DEBU 38972 constructing new tx simulator txid = [344eacf74fbcddd9c9e3c70dbabbe4088c96dd52f98ce2245d1a62ce1e1bbec6]
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.891 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> DEBU 38973 [twoorgschannel][344eacf7] Entry chaincode: name:"lscc"
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.891 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 38974 [twoorgschannel][344eacf7] Entry chaincode: name:"lscc"
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.891 UTC [chaincode] Execute -> DEBU 38975 Entry
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.899 UTC [chaincode] handleMessage -> DEBU 38976 [344eacf7] Fabric side handling ChaincodeMessage of type: GET_STATE in state ready
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.899 UTC [chaincode] HandleTransaction -> DEBU 38977 [344eacf7] handling GET_STATE from chaincode
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.899 UTC [chaincode] HandleGetState -> DEBU 38978 [344eacf7] getting state for chaincode lscc, key ccex, channel twoorgschannel
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.899 UTC [statecouchdb] GetState -> DEBU 38979 GetState(). ns=lscc, key=ccex
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.899 UTC [couchdb] ReadDoc -> DEBU 3897a [twoorgschannel_lscc] Entering ReadDoc()  id=[ccex]
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.899 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 3897b Entering handleRequest()  method=GET  url=http://couchdbp1o1:5984  dbName=twoorgschannel_lscc
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.899 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 3897c Request URL: http://couchdbp1o1:5984/twoorgschannel_lscc/ccex?attachments=true
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.900 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 3897d HTTP Request: GET /twoorgschannel_lscc/ccex?attachments=true HTTP/1.1 | Host: couchdbp1o1:5984 | User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1 | Accept: multipart/related | Authorization: Basic cGVlcjEtb3JnMTpwMW8xY2RicHc= | Accept-Encoding: gzip |  |
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.903 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 3897e Error handling CouchDB request. Error:not_found,  Status Code:404,  Reason:missing
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.903 UTC [couchdb] ReadDoc -> DEBU 3897f [twoorgschannel_lscc] Document not found (404), returning nil value instead of 404 error
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.903 UTC [chaincode] HandleGetState -> DEBU 38980 [344eacf7] No state associated with key: ccex. Sending RESPONSE with an empty payload
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.903 UTC [chaincode] HandleTransaction -> DEBU 38981 [344eacf7] Completed GET_STATE. Sending RESPONSE
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.903 UTC [msp] GetManagerForChain -> DEBU 38982 Returning existing manager for channel 'twoorgschannel'
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.903 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 38983 0xc002630cb0 gate 1578660861903990932 evaluation starts
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.904 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 38984 0xc002630cb0 signed by 0 principal evaluation starts (used [false])
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.904 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 38985 0xc002630cb0 processing identity 0 with bytes of aa61b0
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.904 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 38986 0xc002630cb0 principal matched by identity 0
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.904 UTC [msp.identity] Verify -> DEBU 38987 Verify: digest = 00000000  b9 8f 40 de 04 73 0f 9d  d5 60 cf 2a d6 4f 41 46  |..@..s...`.*.OAF|
 00000010  16 a4 86 8a 3e f2 0c fe  76 a4 84 44 0f 27 e6 19  |....>...v..D.'..|
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.904 UTC [msp.identity] Verify -> DEBU 38988 Verify: sig = 00000000  30 45 02 21 00 ce 9b 3c  8a 45 99 12 15 55 45 a1  |0E.!...<.E...UE.|
 00000010  06 11 93 a3 9e 1a 5c 32  a6 14 71 1d 1e d1 1f b7  |......\2..q.....|
 00000020  fe 26 8f 35 05 02 20 29  a1 78 44 02 79 ee 7c 25  |.&.5.. ).xD.y.|%|
 00000030  01 c3 ba 23 88 8a fc 83  d1 03 57 14 02 5b 25 a5  |...#......W..[%.|
 00000040  2e bd 4b cb 72 a9 b8                              |..K.r..|
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.904 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 38989 0xc002630cb0 principal evaluation succeeds for identity 0
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.904 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 3898a 0xc002630cb0 signed by 1 principal evaluation starts (used [true])
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.904 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 3898b 0xc002630cb0 skipping identity 0 because it has already been used
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.904 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 3898c 0xc002630cb0 principal evaluation fails
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.904 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 3898d 0xc002630cb0 gate 1578660861903990932 evaluation succeeds
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.904 UTC [chaincode] handleMessage -> DEBU 3898e [344eacf7] Fabric side handling ChaincodeMessage of type: PUT_STATE in state ready
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.904 UTC [chaincode] HandleTransaction -> DEBU 3898f [344eacf7] handling PUT_STATE from chaincode
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.904 UTC [chaincode] HandleTransaction -> DEBU 38990 [344eacf7] Completed PUT_STATE. Sending RESPONSE
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.904 UTC [lscc] putChaincodeCollectionData -> DEBU 38991 No collection configuration specified
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.904 UTC [chaincode] handleMessage -> DEBU 38992 [344eacf7] Fabric side handling ChaincodeMessage of type: COMPLETED in state ready
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.904 UTC [chaincode] Notify -> DEBU 38993 [344eacf7] notifying Txid:344eacf74fbcddd9c9e3c70dbabbe4088c96dd52f98ce2245d1a62ce1e1bbec6, channelID:twoorgschannel
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.904 UTC [chaincode] Execute -> DEBU 38994 Exit
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.921 UTC [chaincode] LaunchConfig -> DEBU 38995 launchConfig: executable:"chaincode",Args:[chaincode,-peer.address=peer1-org1.inuit.local:7052],Envs:[CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=debug,CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_SHIM=debug,CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_FORMAT=%{color}%{time:2006-01-02 15:04:05.000 MST} [%{module}] %{shortfunc} -> %{level:.4s} %{id:03x}%{color:reset} %{message},CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=ccex:1.0,CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true,CORE_TLS_CLIENT_KEY_PATH=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/client.key,CORE_TLS_CLIENT_CERT_PATH=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/client.crt,CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/peer.crt],Files:[/etc/hyperledger/fabric/client.crt /etc/hyperledger/fabric/client.key /etc/hyperledger/fabric/peer.crt]
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.921 UTC [chaincode] Start -> DEBU 38996 start container: ccex:1.0
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.921 UTC [chaincode] Start -> DEBU 38997 start container with args: chaincode -peer.address=peer1-org1.inuit.local:7052
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.921 UTC [chaincode] Start -> DEBU 38998 start container with env:
        CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=debug
        CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_SHIM=debug
        CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_FORMAT=%{color}%{time:2006-01-02 15:04:05.000 MST} [%{module}] %{shortfunc} -> %{level:.4s} %{id:03x}%{color:reset} %{message}
        CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=ccex:1.0
        CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
        CORE_TLS_CLIENT_KEY_PATH=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/client.key
        CORE_TLS_CLIENT_CERT_PATH=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/client.crt
        CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/peer.crt
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.921 UTC [container] lockContainer -> DEBU 38999 waiting for container(ccex-1.0) lock
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.921 UTC [container] lockContainer -> DEBU 3899a got container (ccex-1.0) lock
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.921 UTC [dockercontroller] stopInternal -> DEBU 3899b stopping container id=dev-peer1-org1.inuit.local-ccex-1.0
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.922 UTC [dockercontroller] stopInternal -> DEBU 3899c stop container result error="No such container: dev-peer1-org1.inuit.local-ccex-1.0"
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.923 UTC [dockercontroller] stopInternal -> DEBU 3899d killing container id=dev-peer1-org1.inuit.local-ccex-1.0
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.923 UTC [dockercontroller] stopInternal -> DEBU 3899e kill container result id=dev-peer1-org1.inuit.local-ccex-1.0 error="No such container: dev-peer1-org1.inuit.local-ccex-1.0"
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.923 UTC [dockercontroller] stopInternal -> DEBU 3899f removing container id=dev-peer1-org1.inuit.local-ccex-1.0
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.924 UTC [dockercontroller] stopInternal -> DEBU 389a0 remove container result id=dev-peer1-org1.inuit.local-ccex-1.0 error="No such container: dev-peer1-org1.inuit.local-ccex-1.0"
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.924 UTC [dockercontroller] createContainer -> DEBU 389a1 create container imageID=dev-peer1-org1.inuit.local-ccex-1.0-f2532bdab2fe7249119e8401b1c82ab053b6777ad4cb00bb22aede6087142e64 containerID=dev-peer1-org1.inuit.local-ccex-1.0
 2020-01-10 12:54:21.924 UTC [dockercontroller] getDockerHostConfig -> DEBU 389a2 docker container hostconfig NetworkMode: fabric-setup_fabric-host2
 2020-01-10 12:54:22.108 UTC [gossip.gossip] handleMessage -> DEBU 389a3 Entering, 192.168.176.104:45966 dbbbe9365151588fe2fbd7718dffd7e4d396dee1050f51cc0b8ad6a82568fa8d sent us GossipMessage: channel:"twoorgschannel" tag:CHAN_AND_ORG hello:<nonce:8964227789991808614 msg_type:BLOCK_MSG > , Envelope: 32 bytes, Signature: 0 bytes
 2020-01-10 12:54:22.108 UTC [gossip.pull] HandleMessage -> DEBU 389a4 GossipMessage: channel:"twoorgschannel" tag:CHAN_AND_ORG hello:<nonce:8964227789991808614 msg_type:BLOCK_MSG > , Envelope: 32 bytes, Signature: 0 bytes
 2020-01-10 12:54:22.108 UTC [gossip.gossip] handleMessage -> DEBU 389a5 Exiting
 2020-01-10 12:54:22.160 UTC [dockercontroller] createContainer -> DEBU 389a6 created container imageID=dev-peer1-org1.inuit.local-ccex-1.0-f2532bdab2fe7249119e8401b1c82ab053b6777ad4cb00bb22aede6087142e64 containerID=dev-peer1-org1.inuit.local-ccex-1.0
 2020-01-10 12:54:22.853 UTC [gossip.discovery] handleAliveMessage -> DEBU 389af Entering GossipMessage: tag:EMPTY alive_msg:<membership:<endpoint:"peer2-org1.inuit.local:7051" pki_id:"\333\273\3516QQX\217\342\373\327q\215\377\327\344\323\226\336\341\005\017Q\314\013\212\326\250%h\372\215" > timestamp:<inc_num:1578651106163750235 seq_num:4393 > > , Envelope: 84 bytes, Signature: 71 bytes Secret payload: 29 bytes, Secret Signature: 71 bytes
 2020-01-10 12:54:22.853 UTC [gossip.discovery] learnExistingMembers -> DEBU 389b0 Entering: learnedMembers={[GossipMessage: tag:EMPTY alive_msg:<membership:<endpoint:"peer2-org1.inuit.local:7051" pki_id:"\333\273\3516QQX\217\342\373\327q\215\377\327\344\323\226\336\341\005\017Q\314\013\212\326\250%h\372\215" > timestamp:<inc_num:1578651106163750235 seq_num:4393 > > , Envelope: 84 bytes, Signature: 71 bytes Secret payload: 29 bytes, Secret Signature: 71 bytes]}
 2020-01-10 12:54:22.853 UTC [gossip.discovery] learnExistingMembers -> DEBU 389b1 updating membership:<endpoint:"peer2-org1.inuit.local:7051" pki_id:"\333\273\3516QQX\217\342\373\327q\215\377\327\344\323\226\336\341\005\017Q\314\013\212\326\250%h\372\215" > timestamp:<inc_num:1578651106163750235 seq_num:4393 >
 2020-01-10 12:54:22.853 UTC [gossip.discovery] learnExistingMembers -> DEBU 389b2 Updating aliveness data: membership:<endpoint:"peer2-org1.inuit.local:7051" pki_id:"\333\273\3516QQX\217\342\373\327q\215\377\327\344\323\226\336\341\005\017Q\314\013\212\326\250%h\372\215" > timestamp:<inc_num:1578651106163750235 seq_num:4393 >
 2020-01-10 12:54:22.853 UTC [gossip.discovery] learnExistingMembers -> DEBU 389b3 Replacing GossipMessage: tag:EMPTY alive_msg:<membership:<endpoint:"peer2-org1.inuit.local:7051" pki_id:"\333\273\3516QQX\217\342\373\327q\215\377\327\344\323\226\336\341\005\017Q\314\013\212\326\250%h\372\215" > timestamp:<inc_num:1578651106163750235 seq_num:4392 > > , Envelope: 84 bytes, Signature: 70 bytes Secret payload: 29 bytes, Secret Signature: 71 bytes in aliveMembership
 2020-01-10 12:54:22.853 UTC [gossip.discovery] learnExistingMembers -> DEBU 389b4 Exiting
 2020-01-10 12:54:23.303 UTC [gossip.pull] Hello -> DEBU 389b7 Sending IDENTITY_MSG hello to peer2-org1.inuit.local:7051
 2020-01-10 12:54:23.305 UTC [gossip.comm] Send -> DEBU 389b8 Entering, sending GossipMessage: tag:EMPTY hello:<nonce:6561937245070138732 msg_type:IDENTITY_MSG > , Envelope: 16 bytes, Signature: 0 bytes to  1 peers
 2020-01-10 12:54:23.305 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> DEBU 389b9 Entering, Sending to peer2-org1.inuit.local:7051 , msg: GossipMessage: tag:EMPTY hello:<nonce:6561937245070138732 msg_type:IDENTITY_MSG > , Envelope: 16 bytes, Signature: 0 bytes
 2020-01-10 12:54:23.305 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> DEBU 389ba Exiting
 2020-01-10 12:54:23.306 UTC [gossip.gossip] handleMessage -> DEBU 389bb Entering, 192.168.176.104:45966 dbbbe9365151588fe2fbd7718dffd7e4d396dee1050f51cc0b8ad6a82568fa8d sent us GossipMessage: tag:EMPTY data_dig:<nonce:6561937245070138732 digests:"\333\273\3516QQX\217\342\373\327q\215\377\327\344\323\226\336\341\005\017Q\314\013\212\326\250%h\372\215" digests:"\346\3373\272Q\"\357R\254_\310\303\007\235\206\030\177C\031\256s\315\021\213\036\345_\004\265\234U\223" msg_type:IDENTITY_MSG > , Envelope: 84 bytes, Signature: 0 bytes
 2020-01-10 12:54:23.306 UTC [gossip.pull] HandleMessage -> DEBU 389bc GossipMessage: tag:EMPTY data_dig:<nonce:6561937245070138732 digests:"\333\273\3516QQX\217\342\373\327q\215\377\327\344\323\226\336\341\005\017Q\314\013\212\326\250%h\372\215" digests:"\346\3373\272Q\"\357R\254_\310\303\007\235\206\030\177C\031\256s\315\021\213\036\345_\004\265\234U\223" msg_type:IDENTITY_MSG > , Envelope: 84 bytes, Signature: 0 bytes
 2020-01-10 12:54:23.306 UTC [gossip.gossip] handleMessage -> DEBU 389bd Exiting
 2020-01-10 12:54:23.354 UTC [dockercontroller] Start -> DEBU 389be Started container dev-peer1-org1.inuit.local-ccex-1.0
 2020-01-10 12:54:23.354 UTC [container] unlockContainer -> DEBU 389bf container lock deleted(ccex-1.0)
 2020-01-10 12:54:23.354 UTC [container] lockContainer -> DEBU 389c0 waiting for container(ccex-1.0) lock
 2020-01-10 12:54:23.354 UTC [container] lockContainer -> DEBU 389c1 got container (ccex-1.0) lock
 2020-01-10 12:54:23.354 UTC [container] unlockContainer -> DEBU 389c2 container lock deleted(ccex-1.0)
 2020-01-10 12:54:23.400 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 389c3 TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=ChaincodeServer remoteaddress=172.28.0.7:53286
 2020-01-10 12:54:23.400 UTC [grpc] handleRawConn -> DEBU 389c4 grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "172.28.0.7:53286": remote error: tls: bad certificate
 2020-01-10 12:54:23.660 UTC [gossip.gossip] handleMessage -> DEBU 389c5 Entering, 192.168.176.104:45966 dbbbe9365151588fe2fbd7718dffd7e4d396dee1050f51cc0b8ad6a82568fa8d sent us GossipMessage: tag:EMPTY hello:<nonce:4160894077449461983 msg_type:IDENTITY_MSG > , Envelope: 16 bytes, Signature: 0 bytes
 2020-01-10 12:54:23.661 UTC [gossip.pull] HandleMessage -> DEBU 389c6 GossipMessage: tag:EMPTY hello:<nonce:4160894077449461983 msg_type:IDENTITY_MSG > , Envelope: 16 bytes, Signature: 0 bytes
 2020-01-10 12:54:23.661 UTC [gossip.pull] SendDigest -> DEBU 389c7 Sending IDENTITY_MSG digest: [e6df33ba5122ef52ac5fc8c3079d86187f4319ae73cd118b1ee55f04b59c5593 dbbbe9365151588fe2fbd7718dffd7e4d396dee1050f51cc0b8ad6a82568fa8d] to 192.168.176.104:45966 dbbbe9365151588fe2fbd7718dffd7e4d396dee1050f51cc0b8ad6a82568fa8d
 2020-01-10 12:54:24.894 UTC [gossip.discovery] handleAliveMessage -> DEBU 38a08 Entering GossipMessage: tag:EMPTY alive_msg:<membership:<endpoint:"peer1-org1.inuit.local:7051" pki_id:"\346\3373\272Q\"\357R\254_\310\303\007\235\206\030\177C\031\256s\315\021\213\036\345_\004\265\234U\223" > timestamp:<inc_num:1578651061743771299 seq_num:4412 > > , Envelope: 84 bytes, Signature: 69 bytes Secret payload: 29 bytes, Secret Signature: 70 bytes
 2020-01-10 12:54:24.894 UTC [gossip.discovery] isSentByMe -> DEBU 38a09 Got alive message about ourselves, GossipMessage: tag:EMPTY alive_msg:<membership:<endpoint:"peer1-org1.inuit.local:7051" pki_id:"\346\3373\272Q\"\357R\254_\310\303\007\235\206\030\177C\031\256s\315\021\213\036\345_\004\265\234U\223" > timestamp:<inc_num:1578651061743771299 seq_num:4412 > > , Envelope: 84 bytes, Signature: 69 bytes Secret payload: 29 bytes, Secret Signature: 70 bytes
 2020-01-10 12:54:24.894 UTC [gossip.discovery] handleAliveMessage -> DEBU 38a0a Exiting
 2020-01-10 12:54:24.894 UTC [gossip.discovery] handleMsgFromComm -> DEBU 38a0b Exiting
 2020-01-10 12:54:24.898 UTC [gossip.comm] Send -> DEBU 38a0c Entering, sending GossipMessage: channel:"twoorgschannel" tag:CHAN_AND_ORG leadership_msg:<pki_id:"\346\3373\272Q\"\357R\254_\310\303\007\235\206\030\177C\031\256s\315\021\213\036\345_\004\265\234U\223" timestamp:<inc_num:1578652172167864564 seq_num:1739 > is_declaration:true > , Envelope: 72 bytes, Signature: 71 bytes to  1 peers
 2020-01-10 12:54:24.898 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> DEBU 38a0d Entering, Sending to peer2-org1.inuit.local:7051 , msg: GossipMessage: channel:"twoorgschannel" tag:CHAN_AND_ORG leadership_msg:<pki_id:"\346\3373\272Q\"\357R\254_\310\303\007\235\206\030\177C\031\256s\315\021\213\036\345_\004\265\234U\223" timestamp:<inc_num:1578652172167864564 seq_num:1739 > is_declaration:true > , Envelope: 72 bytes, Signature: 71 bytes
 2020-01-10 12:54:24.898 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> DEBU 38a0e Exiting
 2020-01-10 12:54:24.911 UTC [chaincode] Launch -> DEBU 38a0f stopping due to error while launching: container exited with 2
 github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*RuntimeLauncher).Launch.func1
         /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/runtime_launcher.go:63
         runtime.goexit
         /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1333
         chaincode registration failed
2020-01-10 12:54:24.911 UTC [container] lockContainer -> DEBU 38a10 waiting for container(ccex-1.0) lock
2020-01-10 12:54:24.911 UTC [container] lockContainer -> DEBU 38a11 got container (ccex-1.0) lock
2020-01-10 12:54:24.911 UTC [dockercontroller] stopInternal -> DEBU 38a12 stopping container id=dev-peer1-org1.inuit.local-ccex-1.0
2020-01-10 12:54:24.912 UTC [dockercontroller] stopInternal -> DEBU 38a13 stop container result error="Container not running: dev-peer1-org1.inuit.local-ccex-1.0"
2020-01-10 12:54:24.912 UTC [dockercontroller] stopInternal -> DEBU 38a14 killing container id=dev-peer1-org1.inuit.local-ccex-1.0
2020-01-10 12:54:24.913 UTC [dockercontroller] stopInternal -> DEBU 38a15 kill container result id=dev-peer1-org1.inuit.local-ccex-1.0 error="Container not running: dev-peer1-org1.inuit.local-ccex-1.0"
2020-01-10 12:54:24.913 UTC [dockercontroller] stopInternal -> DEBU 38a16 removing container id=dev-peer1-org1.inuit.local-ccex-1.0
2020-01-10 12:54:24.934 UTC [dockercontroller] stopInternal -> DEBU 38a17 remove container result id=dev-peer1-org1.inuit.local-ccex-1.0 error=null
2020-01-10 12:54:24.934 UTC [container] unlockContainer -> DEBU 38a18 container lock deleted(ccex-1.0)
2020-01-10 12:54:24.934 UTC [chaincode] Launch -> DEBU 38a19 launch complete
2020-01-10 12:54:24.934 UTC [chaincode] Deregister -> DEBU 38a1a deregister handler: ccex:1.0
2020-01-10 12:54:24.934 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 38a1b [twoorgschannel][344eacf7] Exit chaincode: name:"lscc"  (3043ms)
2020-01-10 12:54:24.934 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 38a1c [twoorgschannel][344eacf7] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: container exited with 2
                 github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*RuntimeLauncher).Launch.func1
                         /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/runtime_launcher.go:63
                         runtime.goexit
                         /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1333
                         chaincode registration failed
2020-01-10 12:54:24.934 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> DEBU 38a1d [twoorgschannel][344eacf7] Exit
2020-01-10 12:54:24.934 UTC [lockbasedtxmgr] Done -> DEBU 38a1e Done with transaction simulation / query execution [344eacf74fbcddd9c9e3c70dbabbe4088c96dd52f98ce2245d1a62ce1e1bbec6]
2020-01-10 12:54:24.934 UTC [endorser] func1 -> DEBU 38a1f Exit: request from 172.28.0.6:43260
2020-01-10 12:54:24.934 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 38a20 unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.28.0.6:43260 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=3.043616977s
2020-01-10 12:54:24.939 UTC [grpc] infof -> DEBU 38a21 transport: loopyWriter.run returning. connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
2020-01-10 12:54:24.939 UTC [grpc] infof -> DEBU 38a22 transport: loopyWriter.run returning. connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
2020-01-10 12:54:25.344 UTC [gossip.pull] Hello -> DEBU 38a23 Sending BLOCK_MSG hello to peer2-org1.inuit.local:7051
2020-01-10 12:54:25.344 UTC [gossip.comm] Send -> DEBU 38a24 Entering, sending GossipMessage: channel:"twoorgschannel" tag:CHAN_AND_ORG hello:<nonce:11931184841188006314 msg_type:BLOCK_MSG > , Envelope: 33 bytes, Signature: 0 bytes to  1 peers
2020-01-10 12:54:25.345 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> DEBU 38a25 Entering, Sending to peer2-org1.inuit.local:7051 , msg: GossipMessage: channel:"twoorgschannel" tag:CHAN_AND_ORG hello:<nonce:11931184841188006314 msg_type:BLOCK_MSG > , Envelope: 33 bytes, Signature: 0 bytes
2020-01-10 12:54:25.345 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> DEBU 3

--------------------------
# Orderer error
2020-01-10 12:52:03.681 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] Handle -> WARN 181 Error reading from 172.28.0.6:43722: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2020-01-10 12:52:03.681 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 182 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=172.28.0.6:43722 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=3.104867598s
```

Can anyone help me overcome this problem? 
Error 1:  document not found in CouchDB.
Error 2: TLS handshake failed with ChaincodeServer (Bad certificate)
Error 3: error while launching the chaincode container. (Chaincode registration failed)
I have four orderers running with RAFT consensus on servers.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: How are you running the peer?  Are you using Docker / Docker Compose?   If using Docker Compose, can you post your Compose YAML file?

Comment: Thank you Gari Singh, I use docker compose and the docker-compose file is here: [docker-compose.yaml](pastebin.com/4cdJD3Vc) . The file is too long for a comment.